# Haskell. Parsing command line arguments

Tags: haskell, io, command-line-interface

I am learning Haskell programming language. Now I am studying IO. I'd like to write simple command line util. The util take two files (JSON or YAML), compare them and output the result of compare (JSON, YAML, Plain text).

I think, the interface of my util would be that:

```
my_util "path to first file" "path to second file" -- format JSON.
```

I decided to use CmdArgs. But now, my interface show  so:

```
my_util -f="path to first file" -s="path to second file" -- format JSON.
```

What I was done.

```
data Gendiff = Gendiff
    {first_file ::  String
    ,second_file :: String
    ,format :: String
    }
    deriving (Data,Typeable,Show,Eq)
 
gendiff = Gendiff
    {first_file  = def &=  name "f" &= typDir  &= help "path to first file to compare"  &= typ "String"
    ,second_file = def &=  name "s" &=  typDir  &= help  "path to second file to compare" &= typ "String"
    ,format =  &= opt "JSON" &= help "set format of output"  &= typ "String"
    } &=
    verbosity &=
    help "Compares two configuration files and shows a difference." &=
    summary " Gendiff v0.0.1, (C) dosart"
 
main = print =<< cmdArgs gendif
```

How I can make first variant? How to set the format flag  default value?

Comment: Not saying it's necessarily better, but for learning Haskell it's at least probably more _instructive_ to use [`optparse-applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) instead of `cmdargs`. It has a more generic, verbose and explicit style than `cmdargs` (which does a lot of things automatically through `Data.Data` and is thus concise but also a bit obscure). In `optparse-applicative` what you're asking for would be [`argument`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative#arguments).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's too hard for me yet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would use [`args`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.10.21/docs/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html#v:args). Something like this:

```
data Gendiff = Gendiff
    { format :: String
    , files :: [String]
    }

gendiff = Gendiff
    { format = def &= -- same as before
    , files = def &= args
    } &= -- same as before

main = do
    args <- cmdArgs gendiff
    case args of
        Gendiff { files = [first, second] } -> -- success path
        _ -> -- print an error
```